# iOS automation on Xamarin cloud

Tags: xamarin, testing, automation, xamarin-test-cloud

I am trying on [Xamarin Test Cloud](https://testcloud.xamarin.com/).

I can run test on my local device with this profile:

** But Xamarin run failed with below message:

> Background:             #
>   features/app_regression_master_cases/tc_001_card_front_side.feature:4 
>   execution expired (HTTPClient::ConnectTimeoutError)
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:799:in
>   `initialize'
>
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:799:in`
>   new'
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:799:in
>   `create_socket'
>
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:747:in`
>   block in connect'
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:746:in
>   `connect'
>
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:612:in`
>   query'
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:164:in
>   `query'
>
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient.rb:1191:in`
>   do_get_block'
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient.rb:974:in
>   `block in do_request'
>
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient.rb:1082:in`
>   protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient.rb:969:in
>   `do_request'
>
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient.rb:822:in`
>   request'
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient.rb:713:in
>   `get'
>
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.16.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/http_helpers.rb:59:in`
>   block in make_http_request'
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.16.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/http_helpers.rb:50:in
>   `times'
>
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.16.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/http_helpers.rb:50:in`
>   make_http_request'
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.16.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/http_helpers.rb:29:in
>   `http'
>
>   /xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/inputs/pre/installation/workspace/local_gems/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.16.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/connection_helpers.rb:11:in`
>   http'
>   /Volumes/Data/xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/workspace/xtc-sandbox-runtime-lib/xtc/formatter/patches/calabash_ios_patch.rb:182:in
>   `xtc_start_app'
>
>   /Volumes/Data/xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/workspace/xtc-sandbox-runtime-lib/xtc/formatter/patches/calabash_ios_patch.rb:131:in`
>   relaunch'
>   /Volumes/Data/xamarin/workspaces/pipeline20151207-54352-1a5zuwf/workspace/features/ios/support/01_launch.rb:31:in
>   `Before'
>       Given App is launched # features/step_definitions/launch_steps.rb:1

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set any env variables on the XTC.

For an example of using one set of profiles for local testing and another for XTC testing see [iOS Smoke Test Example](https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/tree/master/CalSmokeApp/config)

When you submit your test use the `--config` and `--profile` flags.